# iOS - Problem to open frame(other view) in view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

I have a view, and a button in this view. When I press this button I need open other view as a frame. Searching I found this post: [iOS -- how do you control the size of a modal view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231022/ios-how-do-you-control-the-size-of-a-modal-view-controller)

I modify this and I doing this in a IBAction connected to a button:

```
View2Controller *screen = [[View2Controller alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; //Line add
UIView *myHalfView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screen.view.frame]; //Line modified by me
[self.view addSubview:myHalfView];
CGRect offScreenFrame = myHalfView.bounds;
offScreenFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame));

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
myHalfView.center = CGPointMake(myHalfView.center.x, myHalfView.center.y - myHalfView.bounds.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
[myHalfView release];
```

But when I press that button nothing happens. I've verified the code runs in debug it step by step.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your View2Controller is initialized without a nibname?

I typically have a xib I built in Interface Builder in and do the following (have the view in the xib be whatever size you want by default if it doesn't change):

```
MyViewController* controller = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[navigationController.view addSubview:controller.view];
//manipulate controller.view here
[controller release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a peak at this it's golden... read the comments in there as well.

http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-tutorial-navigation-controller.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the replies. Finally I do this and works:

First in my IBAction:

```
View2Controller* modalViewController = [[[View2Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2Controller" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:modalViewController.view];
```

Then in View2Controller.m in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1024, 128, 600)];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75f];
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 404, 128, 600)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```