# Howto show an UIViewController over a UIViewcontroller as like a Popoverview

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

Difficult to explain for me :-)

I already have:
A main UIViewController/UIView -> works
A second UIViewController/UIView which I show after a button is pressed -> works, second UIViewController/UIView is shown on top of screen and has the full screensize, so I can't see the first UIViewController/UIView

Because I realized my secondView holds only some small components, I would like:
to show the second UIViewController/UIView over the first as like a popoverview, So the second is sized minimal and the first is still shown in the back.

I thought I could do simply the following:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Options") as! UIViewController

    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover <<-- Make simply Modal ?

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But still the second is shown on full screen.
Any help ?

**Update I just managed to do by combining stuff found in the internet without knowing what I exactly I am doing :-)**

func showoptions(){

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Options") as! UIViewController

controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

let popoverPresentationController = controller.popoverPresentationController

// result is an optional (but should not be nil if modalPresentationStyle is popover)
if let _popoverPresentationController = popoverPresentationController {

    // set the view from which to pop up
    _popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
    _popoverPresentationController.sourceView.sizeToFit();

    // present (id iPhone it is a modal automatic full screen)
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

The only prolem I have now is, that the size of the modal view is too small, some compontents are not fully visible.

Comment: Not sure, if that helps. Probably I did not understand, but I do not want a popover with an arrow . I just want to show the UIView over the other.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635744/how-to-present-popover-properly-in-ios-8/28158165#28158165

Comment: Take a look at this answer, I posted long ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635744/how-to-present-popover-properly-in-ios-8/28158165#28158165

Comment: take a look a this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635744/how-to-present-popover-properly-in-ios-8/28158165#28158165

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `controller.preferredContentSize` to match your desired size

Comment: Thanks. That heps. Do you know by chance howto get rid of the arrow ?

Comment: I think I did answer that in your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586031/howto-size-the-modal-view-programmatically-swift/31588530#31588530)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
[iOS -- how do you control the size of a modal view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231022/ios-how-do-you-control-the-size-of-a-modal-view-controller)

Bullet points:
1. do not use UIViewcontroller. use just UIView.
2. the first UIViewController's view will be unloaded if u loading a modal view controller.

Comment: I don't think I can use an UIView itself, because I have buttons and interactions with standard control in my second UIViewController. I am not sure. I will check.