# Howto Size the Modal View programmatically (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I simply want to present a small option dialog over an existing main UIViewController/UIView , so that on an IPad I would see a small Dialog and in the Background I will see the Main View.

I managed to show a UIViewController/UIView in a modal view style as follow:

```
func showoptions(){

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Options") as! UIViewController

    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

    let popoverPresentationController = controller.popoverPresentationController

    // result is an optional (but should not be nil if modalPresentationStyle is popover)
    if let _popoverPresentationController = popoverPresentationController {

        // set the view from which to pop up
        _popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;

        //_popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(60, 100, 500, 500)
        //_popoverPresentationController. .setPopoverContentSize(CGSizeMake(550, 600), animated: true)
        //_popoverPresentationController.sourceView.sizeToFit();

        // present (id iPhone it is a modal automatic full screen)
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But I have still some issues:
1. Howto get rid of the arrow shown at the border.
2. Howto size this modal view. It is shown to small and I would like to fit it to the largest controls in the UIControllerView/UIView.

any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try changing `_popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections` to empty option set
2. Change `controller.preferredContentSize` to match your desired size

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you? Is arrow visible? Isn't it sizing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar and ended up presenting a view controller as a modal with a transparent background over the current context. There I made a smaller opaque UIView with what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks. I know I could do my own view and also I could do my own controls, but why not using a existing concept with the UIViewController. I have interactions with buttons and segmentControls. Is there no way to do this with my UIViewController ?